# Core Text in Cocoa app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, core-text

I have the following sample code which works on iPhone.  It draws the text "Hello World!" on the screen using Core Text.

Dropping this code into a cocoa project in an NSView produces different results.  The font size is scaled much bigger and the letters are drawn on top of each other.  How do I have the text draw the same in the cocoa app?

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CFStringRef font_name = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "Courier", kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);

    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(font_name, 36.0, NULL);

    CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName };

    CFTypeRef values[] = { font };

    CFDictionaryRef font_attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]), &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFRelease(font_name);

    CFRelease(font);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
    const char *text = "Hello World!";

    CFStringRef string = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, text, kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);

    CFAttributedStringRef attr_string = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, string, font_attributes);

    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attr_string);

    CGContextSetTextPosition(context, x, y);

    // Core Text uses a reference coordinate system with the origin on the bottom-left
    // flip the coordinate system before drawing or the text will appear upside down
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CTLineDraw(line, context);

    CFRelease(line);

    CFRelease(string);

    CFRelease(attr_string);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

**iPhone in UIView (Expected Result)**

[image]

**Mac in NSView (Unexpected Result)**

[image]

Comment: This cannot be your real code in Mac OS X Cocoa, because UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() does not exist there.

Comment: Also on Mac OS X we are already flipped - you should remove the flip code.

Comment: The mac version uses [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort] for the graphics context but otherwise it's the same code being used for the screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @matt has noted, this is not the Cocoa code, the origin of the coordinate system is "bottom-left" on Cocoa, and `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` does not exist…

Anyway you need to set the text matrix of the context at least to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`. But as `CGContextSetTextPosition` don't set the position for `CTDrawLine`, you need to translate the text matrix to your desired position.

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);

    CFStringRef font_name = CFStringCreateWithCString(NULL, "Courier", kCFStringEncodingMacRoman);

    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(font_name, 36.0, NULL);

    CFStringRef keys[] = { kCTFontAttributeName };
    CFTypeRef values[] = { font };

    CFDictionaryRef font_attributes = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (const void **)&keys, (const void **)&values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]), &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

    CFRelease(font_name);

    CFRelease(font);

    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;

    CFAttributedStringRef attr_string = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, CFSTR("Hello World!"), font_attributes);

    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attr_string);

    // You need to set the text matrix at least to CGAffineTransformIdentity 
    // Here we translate to the desired position
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x,y));

    CTLineDraw(line, context);

    CFRelease(line);

    CFRelease(attr_string);

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Comment: Right. The core of the problem was the omission of `CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);`

Comment: @matt I edited the answer for the position too, that also need to be set with the text matrix, `CGContextSetTextPosition` don't change the starting position for `CTDrawLine`.